# Unable to locate SHCreateItemFromParsingName (SHELL32.dll)

Tags: visual-c++, dll, shell32, delay-load

Good afternoon all,

I want to set up voice recognition macro's to run on my P.C (Windows XP Professional SP3) so I installed Windows Speech recognition Macros. However when I click on it, it states: 
*The proceedure entry point SHCreateItemFromParsingName could not be located in the dynamic link library SHELL32.dll*. So...

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 then... Clicked on debug - Star Debugging, then Project - Shell 32 Properties - Common Properties - Linker - Input - Delayloaded DLL's, then edit and I typed in /DELAYLOAD:shell32.dll.

However when I click on Windows Speech recognition Macro's I'm still getting the same error message.

Please can you help??!
Kind Regards
AlanTS

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with delayed loading. This error means you've installed a version of the speech library that's not designed for XP (or that you're missing a service pack that updates XP). The error means that Shell32 doesn't contain the procedure `SHCreateItemFromParsingName`, which requires Vista or later - see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762134%28VS.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: You seem to want to believe what you've "heard" instead of the documentation from the people that wrote Shell32 (and therefore should know). The docs don't say "available on Vista, unless you've heard otherwise and then it works on XP SP3." The docs say "Vista", which by definition means Vista or later versions of the OS.

Comment: I've been told that the macro's are able to run under XP as a programmer had delayed the SHELL32.dll on a collwgues machine, also using windows XP SP3. I've searched forums and found that it can be done by delayloading the DLL but im confused about how I can actual perform the delayload task?